# Как сделать input (html) активным при загрузке страницы

Tags: html, javascript, активация, php

Как сделать input(html) активным при загрузке страницы, чтобы каретка ввода уже мигала там, как только страница загрузится

```
<input value='".$row["model"]."' name='model' type='text' size='15'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать это гораздо проще с помощью атрибута [autofocus](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/autofocus)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел: [Setting Focus Using Javascript to an Input Field when the Page Loads](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Setting-Focus-Using-Javascript-to-an-Input-Field-%28Textbox%29-when-the-Page-Loads.aspx)... всем спасибо.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setFocus()
{
     document.getElementById("name").focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setFocus()">
  <form>
       Name: <input type="text" id="name" size="30"><br />
       Surname: <input type="text" id="surname" size="30"> 
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

все очень просто и ни какого js и не надо

> Автофокус создаётся с помощью атрибута autofocus, который можно добавлять к следующим тегам: `<button>`, `<input>`, `<keygen>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`. Для текстового поля синтаксис следующий.

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Вход на сайт</legend>
    <p><input name="login" autofocus></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="pass"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Вход"></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```